# sharepoint 2010 Add new item link is missing on asynchronous postback

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom xsltviewwebpart inside an update panel which i am attaching to a custom list programmatically on first load the "Add New Item" link is visible at the bottom, but upon asynchronous postback the link is not visible any more.

Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the above issue by adding a custom "add new item" link visible on asynchronous postback only